# compactness related to some distance defined on the space of increasing functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I=[0,1]$ and denote by $C^{+}(I)$ and $D^+(I)$ respectively the space of continuous increasing functions and the space of cadlag increasing functions(right-continuous with left limit). Can we find a distance for $C^+(I)$ or $D^+(I)$ such that the set of the form

$$M=\{f\in C^+(I): f(0)=0, f(1)\leq 1\}\left(\{f\in D^+(I): f(0)=0, f(1)\leq 1\}\right)$$

is compact with respect to this distance? I think about Levy metric, but I don't have no idea about that. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The Levy metric should work.  What part is causing you trouble?

Comment: If we set for any $f$: $\tilde{f}: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $\tilde{f}(t)=f(0)$ for $t<0$, $\tilde{f}(t)=f(t)$ for $0\leq t\leq 1$ and $\tilde{f}(t)=f(1)$ for $t>1$

Comment: Then for any $f$, $g$ Levy distance is defined by:$$d(f,g)=\inf\{\varepsilon: \tilde{f}(t-\varepsilon)-\varepsilon\leq \tilde{g}(t)\leq \tilde{f}(t+\varepsilon)+\varepsilon\}, \ \ \forall t\in\mathbb{R}$$

Comment: But i don't know how to prove the compactness of $M$, could Nate Eldredge help me show the compactness? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is found in most probability books and isn't really a "research-level" question appropriate for this site.  But as a quick sketch, here's one approach: For a sequence $\{f_n\}$, we can find a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ such that for every $q \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$, $f_{n_k}(q)$ converges; call the limit $g(q)$.  (This is Tychonoff's theorem: a countable product of $[0,1]$ is (sequentially) compact).   Let $f$ be a "right continuous version" of $g$, i.e. for $x \in [0,1]$, $f(x) = \inf_{q > x} g(q)$.  Now show that $f_{n_k} \to f$ in the Levy metric.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks motivation, and seems like it might have come from a homework problem.  Edited to include more motivation, it might be a good fit here.